# How to three-finger-swipe on remotely using Mac Screen Sharing

Tags: mac, touchpad, vnc, gestures

We have two 10.13 Macs, where I've setup Preferences->Sharing->Shared Screen.  My user would like to use the three finger swipe-up gesture to access Mission Control.  However, the local Mac accepts that gesture for the local machine.  How do I make the remote machine receive the gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the local Mac will always intercept the three-finger gesture.  Same with the keyboard button for Mission Control, or double-tapping with two fingers.
However, we were able to add the Dock icon for Mission Control again, and that gives us access to all of the desktops, which serves our purpose.